# Can I impersonate/auto login an account with Facebook Connect?

Tags: facebook

I'm using the .net facebook api to integrate a web app with facebook. I would like to allow users authenticated to my site to be able to post photos/videos/posts to a facebook page that I control. In some cases I don't want this to be posted through their facebook account, but instead via some generic account that I'll set up. Is there a way to impersonate that generic account?

I'm doing something similar with the google (youtube) api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also FB developer.

You need the [offline access permission](http://blog.geehsien.com/2009/02/01/getting-offline-access-with-fbprompt-permission/) for that. There is no other way as far as i know.